# Showing error "Connection string is empty" in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

When i am installing an extension in my magento admin,it shows `Connection string is empty`.
I don't know why this problem occurs. I cleared the cache also then also the problem is same.
If anyone knows how to do this,please help me out.
Thanks!

Comment: Here is the first result of googling your doubt.. Check this http://www.creare.co.uk/magento-connect-error-connection-string-is-empty

Comment: where i will get this. please tell me the path where i will get the box to change

Comment: One more thing beofre making the above modifications. First modify the permissions to 777 to total magento application. Then after installing the extension rollback the permissions to 755

Comment: can you please tell me how to modify permissions to 777 to total magento application.please elaborate

Comment: linux SSH server/cloud server

Comment: what is the path for your magento application in your linux SSH server?

Comment: file path is var/www/html

Comment: That is a permission issue, please check that your magento root directory has write permissions

Answer (score 12):

To solve this problem, follow the steps below (I suppose you are using Ubuntu):

1) `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magentoInstallationFolder/`

2) Install Magento Extension

3) Restore correct permissions for directories and files respectively

```
sudo find /var/www/html/magentoInstallationFolder/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/html/magentoInstallationFolder/ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

Read more about why 777 permissions are bad and you need to restore good permission code (775) after you install the extension: https://askubuntu.com/a/30635

Comment: In fact, just changing app/ and /downloader could work too. Greetings

Comment: no it don't i tried to change permissions only for app and downloader folder but it did not worked!

Answer (score 3):

Magento tries to put the maintenance flag in the root directory. Here is the code that does it:

```
<?php
//downloader/Maged/Controller.php::startInstall()
if ($this->_getMaintenanceFlag()) {
...
//downloader/Maged/Controller.php::isWritable()
$this->_writable = is_writable($this->getMageDir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)
```

If you can't change magento root directory permissions just uncheck "Put store on the maintenance mode while installing/upgrading/backup creation" flag.

Comment: That was the right solution for me; settng crazy 777 file permission should never be.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of suggestions to change the permissions to this:

> sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html

Which is a really really bad idea. Have a search for 'Magento permissions' and follow the guide instead. Unless you're seeking to get your site hacked wihin a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Have to change right recursively (chown -R) to www-data:www-data on a directory containing magento (example : /var/www/magento)
Sorry for bad engish

Answer (score 0):

chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/your_magento_folder
That did the tick for me, don't change the owner of the www folder

Comment: Please add a ***lot*** more details to your answer

Answer (score -3):

Type the following command in your terminal.

`sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/<magento folder name>`. Press Enter.

Then it will ask for password if exists for your username.

Once it is done, login and logout the admin and try to install extension which you want

Edited:

Try this for your files:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html
```

and follow the above steps.

Comment: inside var/www/html,all files are there. There is no any magento folder name

Comment: what is the url for your magento admin?